# Gulp always runs "default" task

Tags: gulp

I have a simple gulpfile.js file with the next content:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("test", []);
gulp.task("default", []);
```

But when I try to run "test" task with command `gulp test` it always runs only the "default" task. If I remove the "default" task it says `Task default is not in your gulpfile`

How can I run my custom task from the console?

Comment: I just copied your code and it worked for me.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, works fine, I've tested it locally

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This problem still exists and I can't overcome it. I have recorded a simple [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/SqXslC6hYoKs) that shows my problem. When I recorded it gulp was already installed globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have realized what was the problem. Windows command line doesn't see additional command line arguments, which I passed to the gulp. To resolve this problem we need to go to the registry and fix `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\node.exe\shell\open\command` key.

Originally the value was `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "%1"`. We need to add the `%*` symbols to the end of the string. Thus, our key value should look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "%1" %*
```